# Visual Studio 2013 not running on Chrome after debugging project on IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, internet-explorer, google-chrome, visual-studio-2013

A ASP.NET MVC 4 project stopped running on Google Chrome after debugging it in Internet Explorer 11.

The project is running on IIS Express and after starting the project to debug on Chrome, it's possible to browse it in IE and Firefox but in Chrome I receive a message: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost:58115" as if my project was not running. This happens only when I switch to debug it in IE.

If I run the project in Firefox or IE 11, I can still browse it in Chrome, but without being able to debug it.

How can I solve this? Are there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that after some updates in either VS or Windows the issue was solved.